# 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Url' not found' -- Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have started learning Laravel 5. Following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785). I am getting this error. (`Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Url' not found`). 
I have attached the image of my code here.
[image: code-laravel]

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalErrorException in UrlController.php line 22:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Url' not found
in UrlController.php line 22
at FatalErrorException->__construct() in compiled.php line 1838
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in compiled.php line 1833
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in compiled.php line 0
at UrlController->store() in compiled.php line 8504
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\readit-later\vendor\compiled.php:8504}() in compiled.php line 8504
at Controller->callAction() in compiled.php line 8572
at ControllerDispatcher->call() in compiled.php line 8551
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in compiled.php line 9190
```

help me out.

Comment: This is a namespacing issue. Place `use Url` at the top of your page or write `$url = new \Url()`. This is happening because you're following a laravel 4 tutorial and you're using laravel 5 where you need to specify what you're going to use.

Comment: You forgot to create the eloquent model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a model with the name Url or whatever suits best inside your app folder you may also generate a url model by artisan command

```
php artisan make:model Url
```

or you can create one manually e.g

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

protected $table = 'table_name' // in case your table name is different than plural of model name

class Url extends Model
{

}
```

and then in your controller use this Url model e.g

```
use App\Url;
```

and then you will be able to use

```
$url = new Url;
$url->url = Request::get('url'); //make sure you have used use Illuminate\Http\Request; in starting of your controller
```

Answer (score 8):

In the controller add

```
use URL;
```